# SoapFault exception: [VersionMismatch] Wrong Version

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I made one of SOAP web service on local machine. I call with a SOAP client via the `some.wsdl` file, work fine. But I try to use full host-URL `http://flow.local/soap/some.wsdl`

The index.php (with SOAP) client:

```
<?php
  //Here change the client to 'some wsdl' / 'http://flow.local/soap/some.wsdl'
  $client = new SoapClient("http://flow.local/soap/some.wsdl",
    array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,'trace' => 1 ));
  var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
  $return = $client->__soapCall("hello",array("World"));
  echo("\nReturning value: ".$return);
```

Here is the soap.php

```
<?php
  function hello($someone)
  {
    return "Hello " . $someone . "! - With WSDL";
  }

  ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
  $server = new SoapServer("http://flow.local/soap/some.wsdl",
    array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
  $server->addFunction("hello");
  $server->handle();
```

And of course I have a wsdl schema file.

When I use full URL `http://flow.local/soap/some.wsdl` returns with:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [VersionMismatch] Wrong Version!"

Else work fine.

*Win10Pro, WAMP server, PHP version 7.2.18.*

Comment: Try SOAP_1_1 ? Maybe work

Comment: I restart the apache/php server and works fine... I'll report why if I find the problem in the logs.